# onClick not working on an 'a' element

Tags: php, javascript, html, function, onclick

I have two separate classes in css, and I want the links to switch from one to the other when clicked. I dont even get the alert, so I think there is a problem with the `onClick` part:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function find(word) {
       alert('check');
       if (document.getElementById(word).className == "remaining";) {
         document.getElementById(word).className = "found";
       } else {
         document.getElementById(word).className = "remaining";
       };
     };
   </script>
[...]
<a href="#" id="word20" class="remaining" onClick="find('word20');">LOL</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById(word).className == "remaining";) {
------------------------- E R R O R ----------------------^
```

The spurious semicolon here is the error.

I found the error in Firefox JavaScript's Error Console. It is easy to launch it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You have a sintax error, the script should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function find(word) {
   alert('check');
   if (document.getElementById(word).className == "remaining") {
     document.getElementById(word).className = "found";
   } else {
     document.getElementById(word).className = "remaining";
   };
 };
```

Remove the ; next to "remaining"